# Deserialize a GWT-RPC response using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, deserialization, gwt-rpc

Is it possible to parse or deserialize a [GWT-RPC](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC) response using C#? I can not seem to find any useful information about this ~serialized format.

I get the following response from the service and would like to use its content;

`//OK[0,1,10,'Tjsknq4',4,6,9,'Tjsknq4',4,11,2,0,1,10,'TjsdwN4',4,6,9,'TjsdwN4',4,8,2,0,1,7,'TjskEwg',4,6,5,'TjskEwg',4,3,2,3,1,["java.util.ArrayList/3821976829","com.initka.onlineinfo.server.datamodel.DepartureInformation/3749734003","49 min","java.util.Date/1659716317","String1","844","A","22 min","String2","B","52 min"],0,6]` <sub>Slightly modified</sub>

I understand that it´s used for communication between server and client side using Java and Javascript but can it be deserialized in C# as well or would it require the data model "DepartureInformation"?

A minified Javascript uses the response to populate a list based on the data in "java.util.ArrayList"/"DepartureInformation" and the output looks something like the following example;

- 844, String2, B, 22 min
- 844, String1, A, 49 min
- 844, String2, B, 52 min

Comment: GWP-RPC is a pretty much closed format. See here on SO about the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135590/gwt-rpc-data-format

Comment: That was a really nice post and the linked power point guided me to http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/t and GwtParse where the request payload is explained very well. Unfortunately, it doesn´t say much about the serialized response. Thanks a lot for the best resource so far!

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend switching from GWT-RPC to RestyGWT (https://resty-gwt.github.io/).  It is a beautiful/simple REST based client for GWT.  Once you switch, you just implement a C# REST-based webservice on the server side and all the json is serialized to a collection of "DepartureInformation" objects for you (assuming the property names match up).