# GWT RPC call from URL

Tags: java, security, gwt, servlets, rpc

I have a servlet that sends emails when a form is submitted, and it works fine. This is done calling from client-side the `sendMail()` that is implemented on sendMailServiceImpl.

My question is about security: is there a way that someone put a specific URL and those emails are sent? Something like `http://myproject.appspot.com/myproject/sendmail?name=aaa&email=aa@aa.com`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sendMailServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gw.myproject.server.SendMailServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sendMailServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myproject/sendMail</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If email is a request parameter why wouldn't that be possible? The answer to your question is probably yes but have you at least tried it?

Comment: I have and I get no-found error. I didn't know if it is because I am typing the wrong address or if it is forbidden.

Comment: Probably not as url parameters, but in the payload somehow.

Comment: Take a valid request (you can use Chrome inspector and see it in the Network tab of devtools), modify it, and see if it still works.

Comment: Your URL looks like a HTTP GET request. I believe GWT servlets use POST requests by default. You should make POST requests, and look at this article for how to interface with the GWT RPC method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135590/gwt-rpc-data-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, that someone send data via GWT-RPC. There are some [attacking scenarios decribed](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/77/Attacking_Google_Web_Toolkit.ppt) by the [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/)

GWT-RPC uses a POST-request. The Servlet will not listen to GET. There are some mechanism included, that will require some knowlege about the request (strongname and serialization policy) and [the protocol itself](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit#heading=h.amx1ddpv5q4m).

But if someone captures a request, he also can send a request.

The request is secured against XSS because of the same-origin-policy. But this will not help against requests from plain java or python or browser which are startet with `--disable-web-security`

Fore some more details: [GWT RPC data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135590/gwt-rpc-data-format)